# Apply Butterworth filters in time series data

Tags: frequency, lowpass-filter, butterworth, highpass-filter, bandpass-filter

I have time series data which are measured in miliseconds (ms) (69300 rows) and I want to apply low-pass, high-pass and band-pass Butterworth filters.

My approach is the following:

- Convert ms into Hz

  - Find the Nyquist which is sample rate/2 (as sample rate I take the converted Hz value)
  - Calculate the sinusoid+noise
  - Calculate the cutoff frequencies for low-pass and high-pass filters (by taking the 0.1 of the total Hz and divide with the Nyquist value for the low-pass, and taking the 0.25 of the total Hz)
  - For the band-pass filter I calculate the difference of the cut-off frequencies
  - Apply the -nth order of the filters
  - Passing the filters with the sinusoid+noise.

Below is a code snippet I made using R:

```
# 69300 ms are 0.014430014430014Hz
x <- 1:69300

nyquist <- 0.014430014430014/2 # sampling rate/2

x1 <- sin(2*pi*RF*0.014430014430014) + 0.25*rnorm(length(RF)) 
# 0.014430014430014 Hz sinusoid+noise, RF is the time series metric

f_low <- 0.001443001/nyquist # 0.1 of total Hz divided by Nyquist
f_high <- 0.003607504/nyquist # 0.25 of total Hz divided by Nyquist

bf_low <- butter(4, f_low, type="low")
bf_high <- butter(4, f_high, type = "high")
bf_pass <- butter(4, 0.3000001, type = "pass") # f_high - f_low

b <- filter(bf_low, x1)
b1 <- filter(bf_high,x1) 
b2 <- filter(bf_pass,x1)
```

Is this the correct approach? Should instead of sinusoid+noise to apply the filter to the metric itself?